# use i18n in other function

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, express, gallery

How to implement multi-language in node.js for template and routers with i18
How can I use i18n in other functions to the language change. 
i18n only generates empty files en.js es.js ... this is so or is wrong?

Example

//app.js

```
require(i18n):
require("./router" );
```

//router.js

```
export.example = function (){
    .
    .
    .
    req.session.error = __('You have error:  %s', error);
}
```

500 TypeError: Object # has no method '__'

Comment: I have no idea what are you asking for.

Comment: I did change the question, if you can to help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the app with i18n internationalization, it is best used only in the final template with this is easier to edit for other languages ​​and not have to search the texts throughout our code.

Use jade for internationalization as follows

```
#{__('Hello')}
```

I followed the other information as the [reference says.](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node)